# Javascript - how to make true after clicking 2 buttons

Tags: javascript

I have 3 buttons.

Button #1 and Button #2 and Button #3

After they have clicked #1 and #2, button #3 will activate and they can click on it.
Thank you so much.

This is what I have done so far:

```
var l50K_WC = false;
var l6OK_WC = false;
function share()
{
   alert('yo');
}
function getIt_wc()
{
   if(l5OK_WC && l6OK_WC)
      window.open('http://websitehere.ca','_self');

   if(!l5OK_WC)
      alert("Click Button #1)");
   else if(!l6OK_WC)
      alert("Click Button #2)");
}
```

This displays the message, but how do I finish the rest where they have to click the 2 buttons before continuing? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the values for the both other buttons to true:

```
var l50K_WC = false;
var l6OK_WC = false;

function click1(){
  150K_WC = true;
}

function click2(){
  160K_WC = true;
}


function share()
{
   alert('yo');
}
function getIt_wc()
{
   if(l5OK_WC && l6OK_WC)
      window.open('http://websitehere.ca','_self');

   if(!l5OK_WC)
      alert("Click Button #1)");
   else if(!l6OK_WC)
      alert("Click Button #2)");
}
```

And then in the html Code:

```
 <input type="button" value="150KWC" onclick="click1()">
 <input type="button" value="160KWC" onclick="click2()">
 <input type="button" value="Final Button" onclick="getIt_wc()">
```

Comment: How would I insert the button links and image? Thanks a lot!

Comment: It seems the buttons do not display any message when clicked? What is wrong? thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Javascript
var button1Clicked = false;
var button2Clicked = false;
if (button1Clicked && button2Clicked) {
    document.writeln("<button>Button 3</button>");
}


<!--HTML-->
<button onclick="javascript:button1Clicked=true;">Button 1</button>
<button onclick="javascript:button2Clicked=true;">Button 2</button>
```